# Click on border don't activate event

Tags: html, css, angularjs, click, border

I have problem with using animation in css and event handler in JS.
I have to specific styles for my button (normal and with :active suffix). This solution let's me simulate 'clicking button'. In Html(this is angular directive) I have directive ng-click on that button but it only runs event when I click body of a button not border. But my css sets pointer on the border and there is animation an on clicking border too.

I am looking for the best practice/solution to repair that incident. Maybe I must leave css style with active suffix or add something to my styles.

CSS

```
#addButton {
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: linear-gradient(#92AFDE, #668FED);
    border: solid 2px #14438F;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#addButton:ACTIVE {
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <img ng-click="selectCard()" style="width: 150px; height: 200px;"   ng-src="cards/\{{cardId}}.png"></img>
    <button  ng-click="addCard()" id="addButton">Add<div class="count">0</div></button>
    <div id="delButton">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps a [mcve] would be useful

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4zkzvbw/3/ i've aded the simplest example

Comment: I'm confused...do you want the animation to run on clicking the border or not because it clearly *does* work when clicking the border.

Comment: when you click bottom border the animation starts, but this event don't run function in JS.

Comment: Function runs in the fiddle...https://jsfiddle.net/w4zkzvbw/6/

Comment: This don't works on the highest ponts of bottom in my browser mozzila

Comment: OK i know where is the problem. If i click on the button the "activate" suffix moves the button down and browser don't notice click on this button because pointer is outside my div (after moving)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you specify border it comes after the actual width of the element.

**Use**

```
#addButton{
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

This css property will merge the border space in actual width.

Comment: its working..you are not using `;` after `box-sizing:border-box`. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w4zkzvbw/5/

Comment: Yes it's works but when you clicks bottom border this doesn't work. Maybe other solution?

Comment: OK i know where is the problem. If i click on the button the "activate" suffix moves the button down and browser don't notice click on this button because pointer is outside my div (after moving)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on a project I am developing. I used the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38826326/7622397. But it didn't work. Clicking on border does not fire the click event. But it's important to add `box-sizing: border-box` (as mentioned in the answer) to make sure the below mentioned workaround works

The reason mentioned in the comment seems to be correct

> OK i know where is the problem. If i click on the button the "activate" suffix moves the button down and browser don't notice click on this button because pointer is outside my div (after moving)

As a workaround, I created a div outside the button, gave a `padding-top` css (value is same or greater as the height of translateY) and give the onClick event to the div and not the button. I know, it's not a tidy fix, but it certainly works.

Code for reference

```
.sw-form-button-card {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #668ad8;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #627295;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.sw-form-button-card:active {
    -ms-transform: translateY(2px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
    transform: translateY(2px);
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

HTML part:

```
<div data-bind="click: () => openDDDialog()" style="padding-top: 5px;">
    <button class="sw-form-button-card">
        <span style="font-size: 15px;" data-bind="text: 'Button text'"></span></div>
    </button>
</div>
```